# Full Calendar Event Height in Month View

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

[image]

I have Full calender issue here i have two events

1. 16 to 19th events are shown in view( which is visible as 16-18th dates only)
2. Another event from 17-18th ( which is behind the 1st event not visible though)

> in console.log($('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents'));
>   I get two events in expected format
>   pls help with this

Comment: provide a more minimalistic style ,so that anything will be visible

Comment: No additional styles are provided expect the default of the calendar..

Comment: customize the default css

Comment: Is this a Bug in Fullcalendar?

Comment: no,just multiple events on the month is a bit fussy, one overwriting others. Don't hesitate to customize.

Comment: On FullCalendar demo they have similar demo with 2 events at the same date that works fine. You probably have some style that override the calendar default css. Try to remove all other css files and if the issue still exist download FullCalendar css again.